# Is it possible to disable this button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I disable or hide this "Signin" button. I want this "Signin" button to just be able to click one time.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let visitorToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
            context.delete(visitorToDelete)
            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
    })

    let SigninAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Signin",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        let SigninVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SigninVC") as! SignatureViewController
        self.present(SigninVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let cellID = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! VisitorTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        let results = cell.tag
        SigninVC.lastnumber = results
    })
    return [deleteAction,SigninAction]
}
```

Comment: Please specify your question. Is it about making a visual change to the button or about stopping it from doing something? Also from your code excerpt not much can be learned about the button (it seems part of a Storyboard).

Comment: Are you maybe just looking for `isEnabled`?

Comment: Hi Garrett, I want to stop it from doing something.
Because the button when I clicked it. it will show another page.
I just want it can click one time. if want to click this button again is impossible.
But I can't use isEnabled for this case.

Comment: It would be nice if you show the code of your button ... So in your case its a signIn Button therefor you should add a target to your button which executes some code. Inside that Code you can do what ever you want like disable the button , open new view controller etc.